# вывести данные в list_display

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Здравствуйте, нужна ваша помощь. Допустим есть данные модели

models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

необходимо вывести `was_published_recently` в классе class `Choice(admin.ModelAdmin)`:

admin.py

```
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('question_text', 'pub_date', 'was_published_recently')

class Choice(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('question, 'choice_text', 'votes')
```

Comment: А не хотите просто сделать Choice инлайном для Question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

```
def was_published_recently(self):
    now = timezone.now()
    return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now
was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
was_published_recently.boolean = True
was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

   def func(self):
    return self.question.was_published_recently()

class Choice(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('question, 'choice_text', 'votes','func',)
```

Попробуй, у меня так вышло